# How did Saladin obtain iced water in the middle of the desert?

Tags: plot-explanation, kingdom-of-heaven

This question never stopped to bother me. 
I have looked for answers but all I could find was along the lines of :

Snow fell from the sky during the harsh cold winter. 
It is collected and stored (somehow) and maintained until summer.

This answer suggests that it costs a fortune to do so, which is shown in the (Saladin's generosity).

The ice shown in the movie is not just any ice.. It is a slush-consistency ice.

How did they manage to make it back then (if every they did).

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/287ppm/in_kingdom_of_heaven_you_can_see_at_one_point/

Answer (score 8):

Although it sounds unbelievable, in ancient times (even in the desert) they had the ability to store ice.

There are a few different sources for this information online. Firstly, [there is this article](http://www.ipcbee.com/vol1/44-B084.pdf) written by some Malaysian architecture students. Their research stated:

> In 440 BC Iran, Iranian people had already domination the technique
>   of ***storing ice in the middle of summer in the desert.*** The ice was
>   brought in during the winters from nearby mountains in bulk amounts,
>   and stored in a specially designed, passively cooled refrigerator,
>   called an Earth refrigerator. This was a large underground space that
>   had thick walls made out of a special mortar called sarooj, composed
>   of sand, clay, egg whites, lime, goat hair, and ash in specific
>   proportions, and which was resistant to heat transfer.

This is backed up by other sources, such as the medical book *[Cutaneous Cryosurgery](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=LYPSBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA1&lpg=PA1&dq=ice%20storage%20ancient%20times%20desert&source=bl&ots=qksCDd7iUW&sig=vdd3fNNPO8I1gjXFhgzSbQGrfmQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwii3PmS2_DKAhXEWRoKHQ62Cn84ChDoAQglMAE#v=onepage&q=ice%20storage%20ancient%20times%20desert&f=false)*, which look at this issue in relation to ancient medicine. It stated:

> At first glance it is not clear how ice or snow would have been
>   available at such latitudes, but even in hot countries there were
>   means of acquiring it. Ice could be stored, from the winter time, in
>   ice houses where it was packed in large quantities and covered with
>   straw or other insulating materials...***Ingenuity was at its foremost
>   when methods were developed to produce ice or slush in desert areas
>   when extreme low temperatures at night were manipulated to freeze
>   evaporating water***. The Romans and later Iranians would dig a pit and
>   line it with insulating straw. In it was placed a water contained and
>   the opening was covered by a sun-reflecting shiny metal in the day but
>   open to the elements at night. Evaporation at night led to ice forming
>   around the edge of the container. This was collected and stored.

So as unusual as it might as first sound, the ancients certainly had the ability and know-how to do this.